# How to transform one integer into two and to inverse the transformation easily?

Tags: algorithm, sql-server-2005, optimization, integer, bit-manipulation

I have a couple of integer (x,y) where    0 < y <= x <= 6.
I need to store them into one column only, named z.
I want to have the three functions F1, F2, F3 to solve this :

z=F1(x,y)
x=F2(z)
y=F3(z)

My first approach :

F1 : 10*y+x
F2 : (z-z%10)/10
F3 : z%10

I have to use it in a `WHERE` clause over a table with millions of lines.
Any better idea ?

Comment: Are `x` and `y` always positive?

Comment: Shouldn't it be `F1(x, y) = 10 * y + x` instead? Also, if those are regular binary integers, use 8 instead of 10. It may be faster.

Comment: 16, not 8. And may be, even 256

Comment: Hi! And who will mark the answer?

Answer (score 1):

I would use:

```
  F1 : z=10*x+y
  F2 : x=z/10
  F3 : y=z-F2*10
```

Maybe, if you take 16 base, it would be innerly optimized? And I would try the base of 256 - thus one digit lies in one byte.

```
F1 : z=256*x+y
F3 : y=z&255   // that is definitely faster
F2 : x=z/256
```

As SQL-server doesn't have the >> or << operators, that's the end, I am afraid.

Comment: Not if z was made of x and y, neither of them was 0. It is a bitwise operation - you simply take lower 8 bits. But sorry, maybe SQL-server doesn't have bitwise operations on integers? Then simply use 256 instead of 10 and hope for optimalization.

Comment: y = z- z/10 *10 can be simplify by y=0 (^_^)

Comment: No, the integer division will give, for example, 15/10->1, 1*10->10 and the difference is 5 that we searched for. I strongly advice you to read at least *something* on integer operations